# Is academic Jewish studies considered learning torah?

Tags: torah-study

Would the academic study of Judaism such as a typical bible studies course taught in a Jewish Studies department at a University qualify as torah study? I am curious about this both halachicly - would one fulfill the halachic obligation to study torah with this study? As well as hashkaficly, would such study be of equal value to traditional torah study?

Comment: Wouldn't it just depend on what is being taught? "Academic Jewish studies" isn't a category recognized by Halakha that you can expect Halakha to have addressed it.

Comment: Do university Jewish Studies departments actually teach from a Jewish perspective, or do they study Judaism "clinically' from the outside?

Comment: I doubt you can get tenure in any Jewish Studies department unless you accept and teach the so-called "Documentary Hypothesis".  So I would answer no.  However, it is better than nothing, because it can get you started studying on your own.